# How do I compare and update this array based on another array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on this [challenge—Inventory update](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/inventory-update), on Free CodeCamp.com
The challenge states:

> Compare and update the inventory stored in a 2D array against a second
>   2D array of a fresh delivery. Update the current existing inventory
>   item quantities (in arr1). If an item cannot be found, add the new
>   item and quantity into the inventory array. The returned inventory
>   array should be in alphabetical order by item.

```
function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {
    for (var x = 0; x < arr1.length; x++) {

        for (var y = 0; y < arr2.length; y++) {

            if (arr1[x][1] === arr2[y][1]) {
                arr1[x][0] = arr2[y][0]  + arr1[x][0];
            }
        }
    }

 for(var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){

     var i = arr2[j][1];

     for(var k = 0; k < arr1.length; k++){
         var idx = arr1.indexOf(i);
          if(idx === -1){
             arr1.push(i);
          }
     }


}
return arr1;

}
```

When I try:

```
updateInventory([[21, "Bowling Ball"], [2, "Dirty Sock"], 
[1, "Hair Pin"], [5, "Microphone"]], [[2, "Hair Pin"], 
[3, "Half-Eaten Apple"], [67, "Bowling Ball"], 
[7, "Toothpaste"]]).length // I get 8 instead of 6
```

When I try:

```
updateInventory([[21, "Bowling Ball"], [2, "Dirty Sock"], 
[1, "Hair Pin"], [5, "Microphone"]], [[2, "Hair Pin"], 
[3, "Half-Eaten Apple"], [67, "Bowling Ball"], 
[7, "Toothpaste"]])
```

I get:
[image]

When I should get:

```
[[88, "Bowling Ball"], [2, "Dirty Sock"], [3, "Hair Pin"], 
[3, "Half-Eaten Apple"], [5, "Microphone"], [7, "Toothpaste"]]
```

I believe this is where my problem is...

```
for(var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){

         var i = arr2[j][1];

         for(var k = 0; k < arr1.length; k++){
             var idx = arr1.indexOf(i);
              if(idx === -1){
                 arr1.push(i);
              }
         }


    }
```

cause it's sort of working. But can anyone help with the alphabetical sorting part too? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {
  for (var x = 0; x < arr1.length; x++) {

    for (var y = 0; y < arr2.length; y++) {

      if (arr1[x][1] === arr2[y][1]) {
        arr1[x][0] = arr2[y][0] + arr1[x][0];
      }
    }
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {

    var i = arr2[j][1];
    var found = 0;

    for (var k = 0; k < arr1.length; k++) {
      if (arr1[k][1] === arr2[j][1]){
        found = 1;}
    }
    if (found == 0)
      arr1.push(arr2[j]);
  }
  arr1.sort(compareSecondColumn);
  return arr1;

}
```

for sorting

```
function compareSecondColumn(a, b) {
    if (a[1] === b[1]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[1] < b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That got the length portion to work, however everything  else didn't pass...

Comment: What is not working ? This sorts the array add items if only they are not already there in first array and adds the number if already present

Comment: Sorry nevermind, forgot the sorter! Thanks you Muhammad!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this as well, I know its been answered but just wanted to give it a go.

```js
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
  var results = [];
  this.forEach(function(subArray) {
    subArray.forEach(function(item) {
      results.push(item);
    });
  });
  return results;
};

function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {
  arr1.forEach(function(item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      if (item[1] === arr2[i][1]) {
        item[0] = item[0] + arr2[i][0];
      }
    }
  });

  arr1.forEach(function(item) {
    var tempArray = arr1.concatAll();
    for (var e = 0; e < arr2.length; e++) {
      if (tempArray.indexOf(arr2[e][1]) === -1) {
        arr1.push(arr2[e]);
      }
    }
  });

  arr1 = arr1.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a[1] > b[1]) ? 1 : ((b[1] > a[1]) ? -1 : 0);
  });
  alert(arr1);

  return arr1;
}

// Example inventory lists
var curInv = [
  [21, "Bowling Ball"],
  [2, "Dirty Sock"],
  [1, "Hair Pin"],
  [5, "Microphone"]
];

var newInv = [
  [2, "Hair Pin"],
  [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
  [67, "Bowling Ball"],
  [7, "Toothpaste"]
];

updateInventory(curInv, newInv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [built in array functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to make things a bit easier to understand. In my example I'm sure you could combine all the functions instead of altering the `oldValues` array.

```
var oldValues = [[21, "Bowling Ball"], [2, "Dirty Sock"], 
[1, "Hair Pin"], [5, "Microphone"]];

var newValues = [[2, "Hair Pin"], 
[3, "Half-Eaten Apple"], [67, "Bowling Ball"], 
[7, "Toothpaste"]];


newValues.forEach(function(nArr) {
  var i = 0;
  for(i; i < oldValues.length; i++) {
    if(oldValues[i][1] === nArr[1]) {
      oldValues[i] = nArr;
      return;
    }
  }
  oldValues.push(nArr);
});

oldValues.sort(function (ov, nv) {
  return ov[1] > nv[1];
}).forEach(function (v) {
  console.debug(v);
  $('#test').append('<li>[' + v[0] + ', ' + v[1] + ']</li>');
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VNksR4eoDLEqU7TSoTj1?p=preview